# Check if device is Samsung S7 and higher programmatically

Tags: android, model, samsung-mobile

I need to run an piece of functionality in my android app, only if the device is Samsung and s7 and higher, is there a way to do it programmatically?

I know how to get device manufacturer and model using

```
val deviceMan = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER  
val deviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL
```

Comment: What do you mean "higher"? Do you mean S8? If so, what are other brand devices considered? Is Pixel 2 XL considered higher or lower?

Comment: @ᴛʜᴇᴘᴀᴛᴇʟ Yes, S8. Only Samsung devices.
But I understand what you mean...